# Postgresql update multiple rows with different values if exists and insert if not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im trying to make a query that updates the row if the id exist and if not exist insert. the following code solves half of my problem, it insert the row if not exist but update all the rows with the same value. What i need is a query that update each rows with a different value.

````
INSERT INTO public.cliente
VALUES (

                        'BRASILIA',
                        'DF',
                        2
                        ),(
                        'BRASILIA',
                        'DF',
                        3
                        )
ON CONFLICT (id)
DO UPDATE SET city = 'São Paulo',
uf = 'sp';```
````

Comment: I think you can have subqueries in the update section. `set city = (select ....)` I think :/

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me.

```
INSERT INTO public.cliente
VALUES (

                        'BRASILIA',
                        'DF',
                        2
                        ),(
                        'BRASILIA',
                        'DF',
                        3
                        )
ON CONFLICT (id)
DO UPDATE SET city = EXCLUDED.city,
uf = EXCLUDED.uf;
```